# Finding Outlook messages with *****SPAM***** in the subject

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

This article: http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/outlook-help/learn-to-narrow-your-search-criteria-for-better-searches-in-outlook-HA010238831.aspx

...suggests that double quotes will find an exact phrase. However, when I search Outlook 2010 for messages containing "`*****SPAM*****`" I get loads of results that just contain the word SPAM without the asterisks.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, Instant Search does not handle search terms that start with special characters. To accomplish your search, you'll need to:

1. Open Advanced Find
2. Go to the "Advanced" tab
3. Use the "Field" dropdown to select the field you wish to search in
4. Select the desired condition (such as "is (exactly)")
5. Enter your desired search term in the Value field, then click "Add to List"
6. Click the "Find Now" button to search for all messages meeting the criterion you set up

I tried this on my copy of Outlook 2010 with success.

[Solution source](http://www.msoutlook.info/question/389)